# Nested List Comprehension Style in Python by values (chess style)

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a list of lists (8x8) like that:

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
       [17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32],
       [33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
       [41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48],
       [49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56],
       [57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64]])
```

I want to assign black color to even numbers and white color to odd numbers (chessboard style), and display the value element en each cell.

The code I've so far:

```
mtx = np.arange(1,65).reshape(8,8)
colors = 'white black'.split()
cmap = matplotlib.colors.ListedColormap(colors, name='colors', N=None)
mtx = np.arange(1,65).reshape(8,8)
plt.imshow(mtx, cmap=cmap)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is another fancy way to assign True/False values to indices of cells chequerwise:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.colors import ListedColormap

arr = np.arange(1,65).reshape(8,8)
x, y = np.indices(arr.shape)
black_cell_idx = (x+y)%2
cmap = ListedColormap(['w','k'])
plt.imshow(black_cell_idx, cmap=cmap)

#Since it was asked in comments how to display cell values:
for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
    for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
        text = plt.text(j, i, arr[i, j],
                       ha="center", va="center", color="g")

plt.show()
```

[image]

The main advantage of `np.indices` here is that it can be extended into 3D (and actualy any ND) space. It allows to refer all the indices of any array regardless its shape like so:

```
>>> arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)
>>> coords = np.array(list(np.broadcast(*np.indices(arr.shape))))
>>> coords 
array([[0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       ...
       [1, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 2],
       [1, 2, 3]])
```

And you can also access also coords of white cells only with:

```
    coords[np.sum(coords, axis=1) % 2 == 0]
```

These insights were used as a part of project [`numpyviz`](https://github.com/loijord/numpyviz) (disclaimer: I'm its author). You can `git + clone https://github.com/loijord/numpyviz` and draw a 3D chessboard like so:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from numpyviz import VisualArray

arr = np.arange(90).reshape((6,3,5))
va = VisualArray(arr)
cells = va.get_indices_chequerwise(window=(1,1,1))
va.set_colors(cells.T, color='yellow', basecolor='aqua')
va.vizualize(fixview=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Another example:

```
arr = np.arange(64).reshape((1,8,8))
va = VisualArray(arr)
cells = va.get_indices_chequerwise(window=(1,1,1))
va.set_colors(cells.T, color='white', basecolor='grey')
va.vizualize(fixview=True, axis_labels=(None,None,None))
va.ax.dist=12.5 #zoom out a little
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just do:

```
# even -> 0, odd -> 1
mtx = np.arange(1,65).reshape(8,8) % 2
plt.imshow(mtx, cmap='gray')
```

But that won't produce a chessboard for you. Instead you get:

[image]

If you want a chessboard style, you can do:

```
rows = np.arange(8) % 2

mtx = rows ^ rows[:,None]
plt.imshow(mtx, cmap='gray')
```

And:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! 
But I would like to keep the original values.
Do you know how to display the cell values in the same colored image? 
Thanks again !!

Comment: @MigueGIS That seems like a new question, but check this https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html